# Xcode iOS simulator is not displaying the entire content

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, ios-simulator

I am Implementing the basic app in Xcode which displays "Hello World" in the center of the scene. When i run it in iOS simulator it is been displayed towards the right end of the simulated iPhone screen. When i try to place the "Hello world" string towards right in my Xcode project and run, it disappears when viewed in the simulated iPhone screen. How can i adjust this issue. Thanks

Comment: can you share the screen shot

Comment: Not sure what any of those tags had to do with your question so I have removed them all and add better ones.

Comment: Thank you i was not sure which one to tag

Comment: How can i add the screenshot here?

Comment: It is prompting that i can upload an image only if i have reputation of 10 or above, provide me a way to share the screenshot @Danial Hussain

Comment: This is due to size classes. Make sure you set your constraints (or let Xcode set them for you).

Comment: How can we set them and to what values should we set them

Comment: Down voting because this question has been asked a thousand times before and auto layout (the cause of the problem) has been around for 2 years. If you didn't learn it yet then you can only blame yourself.

Answer (score -1):

You just keep the label drag untill you got that image in your builder.[image: see this]

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/FirstTutorial.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011343-CH3-SW1

Comment: I have followed the procedure mentioned int the link above. According to the procedure, the label must come in the center of the view. But its coming towards right with "world" cant be seen totally.

Comment: Please do not post link-only answers ... Tell him what he did wrong!

Comment: @chaitanya Make sure you positioned the label along the blue-dotted lines when you move it and that you set your constraints (manually or automatically)

Comment: I did the same.. it was placed as shown by @DanialHussain in the picture, still the problem is not resolved.

Comment: @DanialHussain please show him the most important step: how to let Xcode automatically set the constraints ("reset to suggested constraints"). I'm en route right now so unfortunately I cannot show him.